# Extract maximums from pandas time series data over fixed time steps

Tags: python, time

I have a data of 3 columns.1 is sensor value reading_date_time_time(dtype-datetime64[ns]) and other 2 are sensor readings wrt timestamp.Readings are taken **every minute** and i have readings for 30 days(43,800 rows).
Now i need to find maximum value for sensor 1 for each hour,each day and each week and the reading_date_time that readings were taken.Output i need is reading_date_time as one column and max reading in other column.Please help to solve this.Data sample in screnshot attached  https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAtLE.png

Comment: You might want to check out this stackoverflow post that address a similar question here.[link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55307132/find-maximum-value-of-each-day-from-hourly-data

Comment: @AresZephyr buddy i saw this post already but cant link it with my problem statement.

Comment: Can you post some sample data. I can try and write something to solve it.

Comment: @AresZephyr https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAtLE.png here is the link to screenshot of my sample data.Is this ok?

Comment: Jayk, there is another piece of information to this problem that is not obvious but relevant.  Are you wanting to achieve your goal only once, or are you wanting to solve this so it can be done with this kind of data routinely.  Like once every month. If only as a one off, importing data into a spreadsheet program, and using good cell formula may be the most time efficient solution. If continuous to say, send onto a website or other program, that would likely need a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have exactly one reading per minute, every hour you have `60` readings, every day you have `60*24=1440` readings and every week you have `60*24*7=10080` readings.

Thus, assuming your data frame is called `df`, this code should do the job (I will only post it for the hourly maximum, adapting to the other cases is trivial you just have to change `minutes_per_dt` to `minutes_per_dt = 1140` for the daily or `minutes_per_dt = 10080` for the weekly):

```
tot_readings = 43800 # total number of rows in your df
# find max per hour:
minutes_per_dt = 60
max_values_per_dt = pd.DataFrame({}) # final data frame where to store maxs and times
for h in np.arange(0, tot_readings, minutes_per_dt):
    df_sliced = df[h:h+minutes_per_dt] # takes only minutes_per_dt rows starting from h
    tmp_max = pd.DataFrame(df_sliced.max()).transpose() # here you have a row with the time and the max values for the current hour analysed in the loop
    max_values_per_dt = max_values_per_dt.append(tmp_max) # append the maxs and the times into your final dataframe
```

The idea is to slice the dataframe in the desired chunks (hour, day or week) and find the maximum on the sliced dataframe for all the columns. Once you have found that maximum for that slice, you can append the result to a final data frame (`max_values_per_dt` **this is your desired output**) to store all your rows corresponding to the maximum of all the sliced dataframes for the desire time step.

Comment: I think tmp_max is getting max sliced values, but without the timestamp, suggested correction (when df has only one column value, otherwise should slice value column):
`tmp_max = df.loc[df_sliced.idxmax()]`